# find words in a text divided in sentences R

Tags: r, string, cpu-word

Hello there I have a text and I'd like to retrieve only the sentences that contains certain words. Here is an example.

```
my_text<- tolower(c("Pro is a molecule that can be found in the air. This molecule spreads glitter and allows bees to fly over the rainbow. For flying, bees need another molecule that is Sub. Sub is activated and so Sub is a substrate. After eating that molecule bees become very speed and they can fly highly. Pro activate Sub. This means that Sub is catalyzed by Pro."))


my_words <- tolower(c("Pro", "Pra", "Pri", "Pre", "Pru", 
         "Sab", "Seb", "Sib", "Sob", "Sub"))

sent <- unlist(strsplit(my_text, "\\."))

sent <- sent[grep(pattern = my_words, sent, ignore.case = T)]
```

using this code I have this warning message

```
Warning message:
In grep(pattern = my_words, sent, ignore.case = T) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How I can avoid this? I want to analyze all words of my vector. I looked at stringr package but I couldn't find a solution.

The code can change anyway, I just showed what I've done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a regex pattern from `my_words` and use it in `grep`.

```
my_words <- tolower(c("Pro", "Pra", "Pri", "Pre", "Pru", 
                      "Sab", "Seb", "Sib", "Sob", "Sub"))
sent <- unlist(strsplit(my_text, "\\."))
grep(paste0('\\b', my_words, '\\b', collapse = '|'), sent, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)

#[1] "pro is a molecule that can be found in the air"     
#[2] " for flying, bees need another molecule that is sub"
#[3] " sub is activated and so sub is a substrate"        
#[4] " pro activate sub"                                  
#[5] " this means that sub is catalyzed by pro"
```

I have included word boundaries (`\\b`) so that only complete word matches. For example, `'pre'` will not match with `'spread'`.

Comment: I'm using the same code for another exercise but with a large character vector (about 10000 words) and I have this: Error in grep(paste0("\\b", my_words, "\\b", collapse = "|"), sent, ignore.case = TRUE,  : 
  invalid regular expression '\baac1\b|\baac3\b|\baad10\b|\baad14\b|\baad15\b|\baad16\b|\baad3\b|\baad4\b|\baad6\b|\baah1\b|\baap1\b|\baar2\b|\baat1\b|\baat2\b|\basp5\b|\babd1\b|\babf1\b|\bbaf1\b|\bobf1\b|\breb2\b|\bsbf1\b|\babf2\b|\bhim1\b|\babm1\b|\babp1\b|\babp140\b| Why?

Comment: I obtained my_words in this way: my_words <- read.csv("table.csv")
my_words <- my_words %>% 
  mutate(names = strsplit(as.character(names), ";")) %>% 
  unnest(names)
my_words <- my_words$names
my_words <- tolower(my_words)
my_words <- unique(my_words)

Comment: I think there is a limit on how big a regex query can be. If it is too big you need to break it down in 2/3 parts and apply it separately.

Comment: does exist another way to do this without splitting my vector?

Comment: There might be but I am not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the words you're looking for as an alternation pattern, with `\\b` wrapped around them to make sure they are matched only when occurring as words (and not as parts of other words, such as pro --> professional) and input that pattern into the subsetting method you have used in your post.
I'd also recommend that you use `trimws`to, well, trim the whitespace:

```
sent <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(my_text, "\\.")))
pattern <- paste0("\\b", my_words, "\\b", collapse = "|")
sent[grepl(pattern, sent)]
```

You mention the `stringr` package. The solution based on `str_detect` would be:

```
sent[str_detect(sent, pattern)]
```